# Generic methods of 'factor' and 'as.factor'

Tags: r, generics, r-s4

I developed an S3 class in R that behaves very similarly to factor variable, though not exactly. The only snafu that I have left in my implementation is that `factor` and `as.factor` are not generics.

I got around this limitation for my own personal use by overriding `base::factor` in the `.onload` function within my package as follows:

```
.onAttach <- function(libname,pkgname){

    # note that as.factor is not a generic -- need to override it
    methods:::bind_activation(on = TRUE)

    # TODO: make a better attmept to deterime if base::factor is a generic or not.
    if(!length(ls(pattern='^as\\.factor\\.default$', envir=as.environment('package:base'),all.names=TRUE))){

        # bind  the current implementation of 'as.factor' to 'as.factor.default'
        assign('as.factor.default',
               base:::as.factor,
               envir=as.environment('package:base'))

        # unock the binding for 'as.factor' 
        unlockBinding('as.factor', as.environment('package:base'))

        # bind the generic to 'as.factor' in the 'package:base'
        assign('as.factor',
               function (x,...) UseMethod('as.factor') ,
               envir=as.environment('package:base'))

        # re-lock the binding for 'as.factor' 
        lockBinding('as.factor', as.environment('package:base'))
    }
    [similar code for making 'factor' and 'table' behave as generics excluded]
}
```

However I know modifying `base` would never fly on CRAN, so I'm curious if there's a workaround.  As @BondedDust points out, I could of course rename my function which is responsible for coercion to ordinary factors (currently named `as.factor.MYCLASS`) to something like `As.factor`, but I'd rather not go that route, since it means users would have to write code like this:

```
#coerce x to a factor
if(inherits(x,'MYCLASS'))
    x <- As.factor(x)
else
    x <- as.factor(x)
```

or

```
if(inherits(x,'MYCLASS'))
    x <- Factor(x)
else
    x <- factor(x)
```

It just feels odd that coercion to factors is not implemented as a generic.

I also tried this implementation of the `.onAttach`

```
.onAttach <- function(libname,pkgname){

    setOldClass(c("MYCLASS"),
                where=as.environment('package:MyPackage'))

    setMethod('factor',
            signature(x='MYCLASS'),
            factor.MYCLASS,
            where=as.environment('package:MyPackage'))

}
```

But I get this error message:

```
Error in rematchDefinition(definition, fdef, mnames, fnames, signature) : 
   methods can add arguments to the generic ‘factor’ only if '...' is an
```

because `factor` does not use the `dots` argument and my `factor.MYCLASS` has one additional argument.

Comment: Experienced package writers seem to just name their class-specific functions with a different but similar name. Frank Harrell generally capitalizes his similar-but-not-quite the same functions (`Function`, `Predict`) or adds a "2" to the end (`cut2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s absolutely no need to replace the `base` functions. Just override them in your package to make them generic.

So, inside your package, do:

```
factor = function (...)
    UseMethod('factor')

factor.default = base::factor

factor.MyClass = function (...) your logic
```

Since your package will be `attach`ed after `base`, this `factor` redefinition will be found first.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question.   The code below has replaced the original`.onLoad` function in my package. This didn't completely satisfy my desire for users to be able to call `as.factor(obj,arg='arg')` where `obj` is an object with class `MYCLASS`, so I put the code from the original `.onLoad` method above into a function called `setGenerics()` which creates S3 generics for `factor` and `as.factor` at the user's request.

I'm pretty happy with this solution.  I'm just hoping that this satisfies CRAN's requirements.

```
# create a virtual S4 class from my S3 class
setOldClass(c("MYCLASS"))

# set methods for the virtual S4 classes of 'ordered','factor'
setMethod('as.ordered',
        signature(x='MYCLASS'),
        function(x)as.factor.MYCLASS(x,ordered=T))

setMethod('as.factor',
        signature(x='MYCLASS'),
        function(x)as.factor.MYCLASS(x))

setMethod('factor',
        signature(x='MYCLASS'),
        # re-capitulate the signature for base::factor()
        function (x , levels, labels = levels, exclude = NA, 
            ordered = is.ordered(x), nmax = NA) {
            ARGS <- list(x=x)
            if(!missing(levels))
                args['levels'] <- levels
            if(!missing(labels))
                args['labels'] <- labels
            if(!missing(exclude))
                args['exclude'] <- exclude
            if(!missing(ordered))
                args['ordered'] <- ordered
            if(!missing(nmax))
                warning('unused argument `nmax` in factor.MYCLASS')
            do.call(as.factor.MYCLASS,ARGS)
        })


setGenerics <- function(){

    [contents from the original .onLoad method]

}

.onAttach <- function(libname,pkgname)
    cat('Call setGenerics() for increased compatibility with `factor`, `as.factor`, and `table`.\n')
```